Is there a way to specify the context of elisp forms in a source block header?
I have an org file where I pass the properties of an entry to a Julia script as JSON:
* Hypothetical Loan
:principal: 82370.00
:nperiods: 60
:apr: 0.13575
:opening_date: 2024-10-01
:closing_date: 2024-10-31

#+begin_src julia-vterm :results output :noweb yes :var json=(json-encode(org-entry-properties))
<<display_amortization_schedule.jl>>
#+end_src

This used to work, but now it's just giving me the properties from the first entry in the file instead of from where I'm executing it, and I can't figure out what changed in my configuration
I am using Emacs 29.4 and org 9.8-pre (release_9.7.9-121-ga43a2b)
EDIT: as @NickD pointed out, I'm missing the :PROPERTIES: and :END: in the original example
To better demonstrate what is happening, I have this org file:
* Hypothetical Loan 1
:PROPERTIES:
:principal: 112000.00
:nperiods: 60
:apr: 0.0675
:opening_date: 2024-09-01
:closing_date: 2024-09-30
:END:

* Hypothetical Loan 2
:PROPERTIES:
:principal: 82370.00
:nperiods: 60
:apr: 0.13575
:opening_date: 2024-10-01
:closing_date: 2024-10-31
:END:

#+begin_src elisp :var json=(json-encode(org-entry-properties))
(print json)
#+end_src

When I execute the elisp source block, I get results from the first entry, not the second entry like I was expecting
#+RESULTS:
: {"CATEGORY":"test2","CLOSING_DATE":"2024-09-30","OPENING_DATE":"2024-09-01","APR":"0.0675","NPERIODS":"60","PRINCIPAL":"112000.00","BLOCKED":"","FILE":"/Users/kagubot/Developer/Projects/amort/test2.org","PRIORITY":"B","ITEM":"Hypothetical Loan 1"}


I cannot reproduce your result: in a brand-new file, I paste the updated contents and then C-c C-c on the source block; the result is : {"CATEGORY":"foo77","CLOSING_DATE":"2024-10-31","OPENING_DATE":"2024-10-01","APR":"0.13575","NPERIODS":"60","PRINCIPAL":"82370.00","BLOCKED":"","FILE":"/tmp/foo77.org","PRIORITY":"B","ITEM":"Hypothetical Loan 2"} .  Can you reproduce the problem with emacs -Q?

I also cannot reproduce the problem.  Tested in Emacs 29.4 using the shown example.

Hmm. emacs -Q loads org 9.6.15 , and it seems to work as expected. I've since updated to org 9.8pre (release_9.7.10-132-g9cbf0c) and now I can't reproduce the problem either. Weird.

I tried it with emacs -Q and a minimal init file that loaded your previous version org 9.8-pre (release_9.7.9-121-ga43a2b) - I can't reproduce it there either. Maybe close the question?

You seem to be running upstream Org mode: could it be that you did an update just before you saw the problem? I'm wondering if you ended up with a "mixed" installation. If you run into the problem again, you might want to do (list-load-path-shadows) and see if you have Org mode files loading from various places. It might be that your latest update cleared up the problem.

@NickD Thanks for you help, it seems to be working fine now. If it happens again, I will check to see if I'm accidentally ending up with a mixed install

I’m voting to close this question because the problem seems to be a one-off and will not be helpful to others in the future. The problem might have been caused by a bad update (and fixed by a further update), but neither the cause nor the fix is entirely clear.
